# Validação de arquivo PHP

Tags: php, desempenho, validação

Eu tenho um sistema de inserção de termos via arquivos CSV, exemplo:

```
09999999;José
08888888;Maria
```

Pego este arquivo movo para o servidor e, após, eu abro esse arquivo para inserir no banco de dados. Meu problema é que preciso validar a inserção, não posso inserir telefones repetidos no mesmo arquivo e, para isso, uso este código para isso:

```
$valida1 = array_search($numero1, $validaNumeroLista);

if (empty($valida1) ) 
{
    array_push($validaNumeroLista, $numero1);
}
```

Após isso faço uma inserção no banco, o problema é que o tempo de inserção aumentou muito.

**Por exemplo:**

Antes de inserir esta validação, um arquivo com até 20 mil linhas demorava em torno de 5 a 7 segundos. Agora, com 1 mil linhas demora acima de 2 minutos. Acima de 2 mil linhas fica impossível inserir.

Tem alguma dica de como melhorar esse desempenho?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize o array como uma tabela de hash em vez de um array normal. Da forma que está a utilizar, com o `array_push`, está a ficar com os indices todos sequenciais, algo deste gênero:

```
[0] => "09999999",
[1] => "08888888",
[2] => "07777777"
```

Isto implica que quando faz `array_search` neste array, terá um custo de O(n). Isto significa que em média terá que percorrer metade do array para achar o elemento, e por isso cresce bastante com o tamanho do Array.

Em vez disso utilize o numero de telefone como chave, assim:

```
if (!array_key_exists($numero1, $validaNumeroLista){
    $validaNumeroLista[$numero1] = true;
}
```

Repare como agora o teste de existência foi feito com a função `array_key_exists`, que verifica se uma determinada chave existe no array.  Caso não exista colocamos uma nova entrada para essa mesma chave com o valor `true`. O valor poderia ser outro qualquer porque só estamos interessados em registar aquela chave como existente.

Outra forma de testar se a chave não existe seria:

```
if (!isset($validaNumeroLista[$numero1])){
```

Registando pelas chaves fazemos com que o array seja utilizado como uma tabela de hash, e que fique então com o seguinte aspeto:

```
["09999999"] => true,
["08888888"] => true,
["07777777"] => true
```

Neste caso a pesquisa da chave é de custo constante O(1), e por isso será muito mais rápido

Comment: Obrigado Isac, pela informação do desempenho e pela resolução,
no meu caso deu certo com a opção:
if (!array_key_exists($numero1, $validaNumeroLista)){
    $validaNumeroLista[$numero1] = true;
}